# I need an Integer but its a string with a comma

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tuples

I'm using sqlite3 and trying to get the oid by using the title of the row and then trying to use that oid to update a column in my table.

allOID is a tuple, and when I print it i get this:

```
>>> <class 'tuple'>
>>> [(1,)]
```

I'm trying to get the integer out of this tuple but the comma is throwing it off and I can't seem to get it.

Here is all of the code being used currently:

```
c.execute("""SELECT oid FROM books 

    WHERE title = :title""",
    {
    'title': title
    })
allOID = c.fetchall()
print(type(allOID[0]))
print(allOID)

c.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
    
c.execute("""UPDATE books SET
    rented = :rented

    WHERE oid = :oid""",
    {
    'rented': rentedVar,

    'oid': allOID[0]
    })
```

any help and comments are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The comma just indicates that it is a tuple with a single element.

Access it using `allOID[0][0]`.

`allOID[0]` gets you the tuple out of the list of results, going one level further with `allOID[0][0]` gets you the first element of the tuple.

For more info, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> Empty tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but effective.